# fortran dynamic string in namelist

Tags: string, dynamic, file-io, fortran

In order to use quasi-dynamic string for  namelists I wrote the following code

```
    program main
implicit none
      integer::inputlen
      character(len=:),ALLOCATABLE::input
      namelist /ttdata/ input,inputlen

      ALLOCATE(character(len=10) :: input)
      input(:)=' '
      print *,'1.input="',input,'"'

      open ( unit=10,STATUS='OLD',file='input.namelist')
      read(10,nml=ttdata)
      print *,'2.input="',input,'"'
      if(inputlen.gt.10) then
        close(10)
        deallocate(input)

        allocate(character(len=inputlen) :: input)
        input(:)=' '
        print *,'3.input="',input,'"'
        open ( unit=10,STATUS='OLD',file='input.namelist')
      endif
      read(10,nml=ttdata)
      print *,'4.input="',input,'"'
     close(10)

end
```

input.namelist

```
&ttdata
  inputlen=20,
  input='123456789012345'/
```

The output

```
 1.input="          "
 2.input="1234567890"
 3.input="                    "
 4.input="1234567890          "
```

I expexted the output

```
    ...
   4.input="123456789012345      "
```

It seems that memory is allocated in exact way yet reading into the namelist is faulty.
pgfortran ce is used.
What did I wrong? Or what could I do for a program's proper way behavior?

Turns out it was pgfortran 17.4-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp core2 all along. gfortran works just fine.

From pgroup:

> I have successfully replicated your behavior with the latest 17.9
>   release.  We have assigned the problem TPR 24817.

Comment: *What did I wrong?*  You did not write `implicit none` as the first line in your program (after the line beginning `program` and any `use` statements that is, but judging by what you have shown you probably don't have those lines anyway). You did not write `implicit none` as the first line in your program. You did not write `implicit none` as the first line in your program. You did not write `implicit none` as the first line in your program.

Comment: To reinforce the previous comment, I doubt the example output is a result of the example program: `print *,'3.inputp="',inputp,'"'` is in the program but the output looks like `3.input="                    "`.  Please show the program exactly as it is, an make a [mcve].

Comment: Listed full code of the example.
implicit none does nothing.

Comment: *implicit none does nothing.*  It most certainly does, it prevents use of variables which have not previously been declared, and has enabled you to modify your code to eliminate the typos.  At this stage you need to describe very clearly what problems you still face.  For me that (revised) code and input file work as you expect.

Comment: at first input has length of 10 symbols it crops input string in the input.namelist. 
Further ward  it has 20 available symbols yet it reads only 10 instead of 15

Comment: Which compiler, which version and which flags do you use? We have to test your exact code and your exact input file.

Comment: Thanks for a clue. gfortran gave me what I expected. 
The trouble exists while I'm using pgfortran 17.4-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp core2. 

no flags used exept -o

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug then. I would contact your compiler vendor's tech support.

Comment: Already 've done that on forum.

Comment: I suggest to write the edit as an answer here. It is up to you, but I would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the better way to solve the problem was in using alternative compiler.

The problem was reported to the techsupport and was confirmed.

> I have successfully replicated your behavior with the latest 17.9
>   release. We have assigned the problem TPR 24817.

[Report](http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=5750)